# Revising a sentence to make it more clear

Tags: grammar

I'm making revisions on a book from an archaeological museum.

As I was reading through, this sentence stroke me as a bit odd and I need your help correcting it.

> Pottery shaped as horses, ducks, boats, wheels, horns, houses, and shoes were excavated from Silla burials, as were vessels with human and animal figurines attached and pottery with geomatric designs.

I'm not quite sure what the author meant by

> as were vessels with human and animal figurines attached and pottery
>   with geometric designs.

Here's a revision I made:

"Pottery shaped as horses, ducks, boats, wheels, horns, houses, and shoes were excavated from Silla burials, *so* were vessels with human and animal figurines attached and pottery with geometric designs."

My question is:

1. Is the original sentence grammatically correct?
2. Does my revision make sense?

Thank you in advance,

Appreciatively

Yeseul Shin

Comment: Note that _pottery_ is singular, so it should be “Pottery … was excavated”. The writer presumably got distracted by all the plural nouns in between the pottery and the verb, but they don’t change the number of the subject. Apart from that, the original sentence is perfectly grammatical and naturally phrased. (I would probably have written _burial sites_ as well, since _burial_ most commonly refers to the ceremony of burying someone, but since this is an archaeological text, it’s clear enough that it refers to the graves themselves here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original sentence (which is grammatically correct) "as" is a conjunction meaning:

> You use as to say how something happens or is done, or to indicate that something happens or is done in the same way as something else.
>
> *The book was banned in the U.S., as were two subsequent books.*
> <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as_1)</sub>

Your new sentence is a comma splice since "so" is an adverb. See the definition [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so) and the example which shows inversion (like is in your example):

> Similarly; and also.
> *‘times have changed and so have I’*

Your revised sentence would be correct if you change it to "...*and* so were vessels...".

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it. I need your help on one more thing! Unlike other conjunctions that I'm familiar with (such as 'and' and 'but) 'as' seems to require inversion of the verb and the subject, or it doesn't? If I don't use 'as' in that example you gave me, it would look like this;
"The book was banned in the U.S., and two subsequent books were banned, too." Does 'as' take place of 'banned, too'? How does 'as' work?